# Placement new and non-default constructors

Tags: c++, new-operator, placement-new

Can I call the C++ placement new on constructors with parameters? I am implementing a custom allocator and want to avoid having to move functionality from non-default constructors into an init function.

```
class CFoo
{
public:
    int foo;
    CFoo()
    {
        foo = 0;
    }

    CFoo(int myFoo)
    {
        foo = myFoo;
    }
};

CFoo* foo = new (pChunkOfMemory) CFoo(42);
```

I would expect an object of type CFoo to be constructed at pChunkOfMemory using the second constructor. When using operator new am I stuck with default constructors only?

**Solved! I did not `#include <new>`. After this, calling placement ::new worked fine with non-default constructors.**

Comment: Yes - error C2660: 'operator new' : function does not take 2 arguments. Do you have an answer to the question?

Comment: Does placement new with no constructor arguments work in the same context? Did you remember to `#include <new>`?

Comment: I had not include <new> after all! Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To use placement new, you need to include the header `<new>`:

```
#include <new>
```

Otherwise the placement forms of `operator new` aren't defined.

Comment: Success! I cant believe I've been struggling with this all day and it was a missing include file. D'oh! Thanks GMan and aschelper.

Comment: @Chris: Yup. It's easy to forget about these little headers because they're often included by other ones that are almost always included.

Comment: Including `<new>` is the practical answer to the OP's question, but the information given in the first line above is incorrect. One does not need to icnlude `new`, but the relevant `operator new` allocation function must be defined (as a member or in the global namespace). To the OP: to be sure to use the global allocation function you should generally write `::new`, not just `new`, when using the "construct in place" placement new; otherwise you might pick up a member allocation function.

Comment: @Alf: Fair, though I doubt circumventing a member `operator new` is the best intention.